# Django: ORA:01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-models, django-orm

Django Version 1.9.6. Python Version: 3.4.3

I've made a binary field in my model (`flal_file = models.BinaryField()`) for inserting binary data in the database.

Database column is blob field.

I get that error when creating an object (insert).

Commenting out `flal_file` prevents this error.

I don't know why I get this error, since this is a binary field.

Is that a bug with older versions of Django? Can anyone help me debug this issue?

[image]

```
myfile = request.FILES['uploaded_file'] 
b = DocFileAllocation.objects.using('db_test_').create(
                   flal_file=myfile.read(), #binary data
                   flal_id_no=seq_doc_file, 
                   bmeta_id_no=seq_metadata,
                   flal_file_subject=subject,
                   )

b.save(using='db_test_')
```

Comment: without knowing anything about Django it seems like Oracle is silently casting your binary data as a LONG datatype.  Are you able to declare data types before you insert?  If so declaring flal_file as a BLOB should do it

Comment: The question here is that it's already declared in Django model as a binary field but the error talks about LONG

Comment: see here for same issue and a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/q/21197523/851930

Comment: This error seems to happen with older versions of Django. But only on binaryfield

Comment: What is your version of Django?

Comment: Django Version `1.9.6`. Python Version: `3.4.3`

Comment: I read the file in Python and store it in a variable. I noticed when printing it, it starts with `b'`. When i insert a basic string it works without error. I use python `read()` method to read the uploaded file and send it to the database. Issue seems to lie there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by adding the primary key via a database trigger. In the model it should be `AutoField`.

Also when saving the object specify the `update_fields` to avoid primary key issue.