# In Python, Why can't i set attributes to the str class?

Tags: python, class, attributes, primitive-types

```
class Sample:
    pass


sample = Sample()
sample.a = "magic"

print(sample.a)
```

In the code above, i create an empty `class` `Sample` and was able to add set an `attribute` outside the `class` definition. Trying to do the same with an `instance` of `str` but I encounter `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'a'`. Why can't I do the same with an `instance` of `str`. Does it have anything to do with `str` being a `primitive` type?

```
sample_string = ""
sample_string.a = "magic"

print(sample_string.a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most builtin classes in python won't let you assign arbitrary attributes.  You can base subclasses of your own on a lot of them (such as list and dict) and then do so.

str is a bit special because of the immutable nature - essentially python can avoid having multiple buffers for the same string by always using the same one.  You can however still subclass it by overriding new instead of init:
[How to subclass str in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255655/how-to-subclass-str-in-python)