# subclass of str fails subclass of list works .. why?

Tags: python

I'm trying to subclass a string and `__init__()` fails.
subclassing a list works just fine.

```
class StrSubClass(str) :
    def __init__(self, s) :
        super().__init__(s)
```

`StrSubClass("foobar")` fails:

```
 File ".../foo.py", line 3, in __init__
    super().__init__(s)
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Yet it seems to work from a List:

```
class ListSubClass(list) :
    def __init__(self, l) :
        super().__init__(l)
```

```
>>> ListSubClass( [1,2,3] )
[1, 2, 3]
```

On the failure, it seems as if the `__init__()` of base object is being called, bypassing `str.__init__()`.

Any help out there?

*This is my summary of the answer and additional research.  I apologize if it's in the wrong "place".  I'm a long time reader and first time poster*

The immutability of the str is the difference and use of `__new__()` vs `__init__` is the key:

```
class StrSubClass(str) :
    def __new__(cls, s="") :
        return super().__new__(cls,s)
```

Even better from [How to subclass str in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255655/how-to-subclass-str-in-python)

```
import collections
class StrSubClass(UserString) :
    def __init__(self, s="") :
        super().__init__(s)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [inheritance from str or int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673651/inheritance-from-str-or-int)

Comment: yes it does indeed. thx

Answer (score 2):

So, there *is no `str.__init__`*. The `str` class doesn't implement any `__init__`, and thus, `super()` calls `object.__init__`.

Your example seems like a toy example. There is no need to override `__init__` in either of your examples since your implementation simply calls the super-class `__init__`. Really, the implementation shouldnt' override `__init__` at all.

For immutable types, if you want to intercept object construction, you must override `__new__` if that is your intention in your actual code.